# How to access a website localhost(https) from mobile browser?

Tags: mobile, https, localhost

My Environment

- PC: Macbook pro, Mac os High Sierra 10.13.3
- Mobile: iPhone6s, iOS 11.4.1
- Private IP: 192.168.25.38

I tried it.

1. Run https web server(SimpleHTTPServer) https://gist.github.com/dergachev/7028596
2. https://localhost:$port Access website localhost from mobile browser(localhost and mobile are the same network). I tried other ip, but it same here(localhost:$port, 127.0.0.1:$port, 192.168.25.38:$port)
3. Shown message: safari can't open the page because safari can't establish a secure connection to the server

   - But, pc browser can access https://localhost:$port
   - I used http web server(no ssl) too. It can access website localhost from mobile browser.(localhost:$port, 127.0.0.1:$port, 192.168.25.38:$port)

Result

- Http server can access from mobile web browser. But https server cant access from mobile web browser. I want http server access from mobile web browser.

Comment: Have you solved it yet ?

Comment: Yes. I have solved this problem through other web server. But I didn't find a problem in simple-http-server. I use this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Comment: @whilemouse could you please explain more, how to solve issue? i have https://localhost:4001 on my desktop, but when i try run on my ip in mobile , it exactly said your problem

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem through other web server. But I didn't find a problem in simple-http-server.

I tried and succesed https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server